# Angular UI Pagination Animation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How would one go about animating [Angular UI Pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination)?

I have made an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869761/animating-angular-ui-pagination), using jQuery animations, but I'm not too satisfied with it, and had no luck from SO for now...

Any insight or feedback is welcome.

**EDIT:**

Animation example: When user clicks the `Next` button, displayed items fly out to the left, and new items fly in from the right. Analogously for `Prev` button, items fly out to the right, new items fly in from the left.

Comment: What kind of animation you are talking about?

Comment: For example, when you click next, displayed items disappear to the left, and new items appear from the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to animate your existing items to left & new items from right you actually don't need to write any javascript code. You can do it using plain css & angular animation of ng-repeat. Read about animation attached with ng-repeat.

Or there is an awesome site you can use to generate various animation, simply use that. http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
SA